# Get value from item based on another value in jshon

Tags: node.js, json, bash, command-line, jq

I have a JSON object structured like:

```
[{"pid":0, "name":"server", "status":"online"},
{"pid":1, "name":"server2", "status":"stopped"}]
```

From the command line, I want to return the value of `status` from the item whose `name` is "server" (the position varies so it can't just be called with array index 0).

I can't use `jq` because the Node version seems to be affected by this issue at the moment: https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1217.

I'm currently trying with `jshon`, but I can't figure out how to chain the searches. The [docs](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) make it sounds like the `-p` flag should help, but I seem to have nothing left in the stack after executing the first part of the search. For example I get a `stack underflow` error when I try

`pm2 jlist | jshon -a -e name -u -p -e status -u`

which I would expect to print `server online server2 stopped` (which isn't quite what I want in any case -- ideally, I just want to return `online` based on the status of `server`). Open to any solutions, `jshon` or otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) at the command-line without any Node entanglements:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | select(.name == "server") | .status' input.json
$ online
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks! I was thrown off because I'm running this as a bash script within a cron job on a shared server, but I was able to get jq on the server so it's all good.

Bonus question: I need to save the result to a bash variable, and set a default value (the string "none") if it returns null. I'm trying `status=$(pm2 jlist | jq -r '.[] | select(.name == "server") | .status' :-none)` but I don't think the default assignment works after the jq string. How do I do this?

Comment: If you don't need to distinguish between `null` and `false`, then simply use jq's `//` operator (i.e. `.... // "none"`). Otherwise you could use `if . == null then "none" else . end`

Comment: Thanks, but neither of these seem to actually work with null input. Try toggling "Null Input" here: https://jqplay.org/s/gqOMHiwhkj

Comment: Why would you specify -n when there is actually input?  If you want to cover the case that the input itself is `null`, then you can still use the same two techniques.

Comment: Yeah, the actual use case is for when there's actually no input; this was just a way of demonstrating that behavior. Those options don't seem to work for me, either here or with actual null input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some major hackiness and length, you can write a full node script to do it for you.

```sh
pm2 jlist | node -e 'tot="";process.stdin.on("data",function(d){tot+=d.toString("utf8");});process.stdin.on("end",function(){dat=JSON.parse(tot);console.log(dat.find(v => v.name == "server").status)})'
```